# If crypto deposit and withdrawal limits are unknown, will excess ETH deposit be lost?

Tags: transactions, wallets, exchanges, pending-transactions

Binance, a centralized exchange, doesn't publish its daily crypto deposit and withdrawal limits for unverified accounts in its FAQ. If I deposit a large amount of ETH to my Binance account's Ether wallet, will I lose the money that is in excess of the exchange's crypto deposit limit?

(The waiting list for Binance help is currently queued at 70, and the support e-mail function requires a bunch of irrelevant fields like "Transaction ID")

Comment: I do not think anyone can answer that except binance, try the telegram channel of them. and take care dont be scammed

Answer (score 1):

Binance does not have deposit limits for cryptocurrency.

Unverified users have a 2 bitcoin per 24-hours withdrawal limit. So 2 Bitcoins worth of ETH, roughly 53.7 ETH at this time.

Comment: how about the more general question of "what happens when I send  to an exchange an ETH amount that is **in excess of the exchange's allowed limits**"?

Comment: As far as I know centralized exchanges (at least most of them) don't have a deposit limit for crypto.

Comment: Do you have an example of a exchange with deposit limits? I'm sure they would have a policy posted on the website for this

Comment: right i guess now we know why they don't limit crypto deposits